# What is difference between rem and mod function in sml?

Tags: math, sml, smlnj, arithmetic-expressions

I'm working on sml project in which I have to implement these two function **rem** & **mod** for custom datatype.

I know the definition of remainder **rem**.
**dividend = divisor * quotient + remainder**

What is the definition of **mod**?
Please explain me the difference between these in simple words.

Answer (score 5):

In `i mod j`, the result has the same sign as `j`.

In `i rem j`, the result has the same sign as `i`.

You can look up the details in the documentation for [Basis](http://sml-family.org/Basis/integer.html#SIG:INTEGER.rem:VAL).